# Image saving and retrieving from database

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to take an image from my system and save it in the form of bytes to a folder in the server.Than i have to give the path of the .txt file i.e the converted image file to the database by creating a table in it.Finally i want to retrieve it from the database.It should be a windows application.Is this possible?

Comment: what kind of database ?

Comment: We cant give you whole code first show wat you did .. paste your code

Comment: @Jameskumar: as this seems like just another of your "program something for me", you should really reconsider a) your project, b) your question style or c) if you should maybe just pay someone for the tool, as it doesn't really seem like you want to program this and ask programming questions (what this board is for), but just grab something already finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible...

You are just storing the path of the image file that you created.
The path is just going to be a simple string.

While retrieving, you need to take the path from the database and set it as the image source path to the ImageBox in the windows application.

Example:

for selecting the image file.

```
string DestinationPath = "D:\\test.jpg";
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
    File.WriteAllBytes(DestinationPath, bt);
}
//Store DestinationPath into the database.
```

for retrieving and displaying in a PictureBox

```
string pathFromDatabase = "D:\\test.jpg"; //Retrieve from database
pboxDisplay.Image = Image.FromFile(pathFromDatabase); //Assuming pboxDisplay as the PictureBox control
```

hope it helps...

Comment: @Jameskumar, For saving or for retrieving ?

Comment: Both for saving and retrieving.The complete code for what i have explained above.

Comment: @Jameskumar,Both for saving and retrieving.The complete code for what i have explained above

Comment: :here in this code the destinationpath is in D drive my folder is in IIS server.How do i give the path.

Comment: Hey, in your question you have mentioned that it is a windows application... How did IIS come to picture ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

from data base

```
byte bt =  File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test.jpg");
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test1.jpg",bt)

    " bt "   you can upload this byte to Database while retrieving bytes from data base use File.WriteAllbytes ...
```

Comment: The bytes should be saved in the server not in c drive dude.

Comment: bytes wont save in C drive ... read the documentation first ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx